# read cookie in angular js issue

Tags: angular, cookies, asp.net-web-api

Im using angular js, Web API with .net,

tried to set cookie though WebApi, that got success. now i need to read that cookie at angular js controller. i tried the following code,

```
 (function () {
        var controllerId = 'app.views.layout.header';
        angular.module('app').controller(controllerId, [
            '$scope', '$cookies', function ($scope, $cookies) {
                var vm = this;

                //#region check whether logged in or not
                var favoriteCookie = $cookies.get('session-id');
                console.log(favoriteCookie)
                //#endregion
    }]);
})();
```

at here, the console is always be `undefined`.

the api code is as follows,

```
        [HttpPost]
        public HttpResponseMessage Post()
        {
            var resp = new HttpResponseMessage();

            var _UserInfoCookies = new NameValueCollection();
            _UserInfoCookies["UserId"] = "1";
            _UserInfoCookies["UserName"] = "test";

            var cookie = new CookieHeaderValue("session-id", _UserInfoCookies);
            cookie.Expires = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddDays(1);
            cookie.Domain = Request.RequestUri.Host;
            cookie.Path = "/";

            resp.Headers.AddCookies(new CookieHeaderValue[] { cookie });
            return resp;
        }
```

> I have double checked the cookies at browser, which is present there..

can anyone help me to find out the issue why i couldn't read cookies?

Comment: `HttpCookie SenderBranchcookie = new HttpCookie("session-id");
                    SenderBranchcookie["status"] = "TokenExpired";
                    SenderBranchcookie["id"] = userId.ToString();
                    SenderBranchcookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1d);
                    Response.Cookies.Add(SenderBranchcookie);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

following code will help to add cookies

```
        [HttpPost]
        public HttpResponseMessage Post()
        {
              HttpCookie SenderBranchcookie = new HttpCookie("session-id");
              SenderBranchcookie["status"] = "TokenExpired";
              SenderBranchcookie["id"] = userId.ToString();
              SenderBranchcookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1d);
              Response.Cookies.Add(SenderBranchcookie); // Response = HttpResponseBase
        }
```